# Richtextbox undo/redo with datetime

Tags: c#, winforms, datetime, richtextbox, undo

I'm working on a notepad clone using a richtextbox.

I have a "Undo" function that can undo any text entered manually into the richtextbox, but as soon as I add a time/date from the menu (Edit --> Time/Date), I'm unable to undo the time/date text.

Here is my "Undo" code

```
richtextbox1.Undo();
```

Here is my "Time/Date" code

```
richtextbox1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm tt, dddd, dd MMMM yyyy");
```

What can I do to undo the time/date?

Comment: The code you show is way too little to help you. We can't even nkow what `GetRichTextBox()` does. (If it brings back  the RTB you work on (Why???) you change the Text directly, which will loose all previous formatting, btw). Actually we see no code at all, just two calls to an unknown function..

Comment: That code snippet does not seem useful at all, surely you meant to assign the SelectedText property so the date/time gets *inserted*.  Like Notepad does.  Which fixes the Undo() problem.